# Cant get hidden div on top in ie6

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, internet-explorer-6

I am using JQuery to show/hide a div. It works fine in most browsers except IE6. When I show the div, it ends up hidden behind the other divs instead of on top of them.

You can see what I mean here: http://www.urlgone.com/d055c5/  (http://old.solesurvivorleather.com/static_product.html).

If you mouse-over email list on the top right menu you will see the hidden div 'listform t' slides down and shows on top, but in IE6 it slides down behind the body-wrapper div.

Here is the CSS Code for both divs:

```
#listform {
    background-color:#F4F4EF;
    border:1px solid #8F8A7E;
    display:none;
    margin:0;
    max-width:150px;
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    text-align:left;
    top:30px;
    width:150px;
    z-index:999;
}
#body-wrapper, #utility-wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:950px;
}
#body-wrapper {
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:0 solid black;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE doesn't pay attention to `z-index` in an intuitive way when it comes to positioned elements. If you move your `#listform` element to the end of the code (just before `</body>`) IE should render things properly.

Alternatively, you can place your `#listform` element inside the end of your `#body-wrapper` (just before the `</div>`.) This will place the element higher in the stack than all the items it needs to overlap. Since the width of the `#body-wrapper` is fixed, it should provide a stable offset calculation regardless of user window size.

Comment: That did actually fix the problem but then I have the issue of positioning the div properly. If I have it outside of the div I need it to be in it wont show up directly under the words email list. As I understand it the position could vary depending on the users screen settings. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: You can place it inside the body wrapper div -- I updated the answer above, see if that works out for ya.

Answer (score 2):

In Internet Explorer positioned elements generate a new stacking context, starting with a z-index value of 0. Therefore z-index doesn’t work correctly. To workaround this issue, Give your parent element `position:relative` and set it's `z-index` to the same number as the child element you want to set `z-index` on. The child element should also have `position:absolute`. This is how it should look.

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 10">
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:10;">
        <img src"..." />
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried giving body-wrapper a lower z-index value?